# Think about doing a Lager

Tags: techniques, fermentation-temperature, secondary-fermentation, lagering

My thought process is to get fermentation started, then once the first two days of fermentation has completed. Filling a cooler with ice and water. Then submerge the little Brown Keg (Mr Beer Keg). To keep it at the Lagering  temperatures. Any more advice is very appreciated.

Comment: I have the impression you're going to ferment it at room temperature, is this correct? Is your temperature in the 7-13 C range? If its higher you might get bad fermentation byproducts. My advice: If possible, get yourself a spare fridge and a temperature controller.

Comment: I had an Ozzie friend place his brew bin in front of the air con unit. It definitely kept it cooler than most other places in his house

Answer (score 3):

I believe the Mr. Beer is a 1 gallon size and fits in most fridges nice. However most fridges work between 35-45°. Your target range for lagering is 48-54°F.

**With out electronic temp control, you will literally need to babysit the fermentation.** But you may be able to pull it off with a simple temp strip on the fermentor.  By placing it in and out of the fridge every few hours, but don't let it warm up past 58°. Getting too cold really won't harm the beer, it will just slow down the fermentation.

It's a lot of work for so little beer. *I would suggest sticking to ales until you expand your homebrewing more.* Usually lagering is one of the last styles homebrewers perfect, because of the need for critical temp control.

Comment: Thank You E. Z. Very thoughtful advice. I really appreciate the information.